# Trying to add onclick function to input button

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically i have a button for which i am trying to make the background change when the user clicks on it.

I know how to do it but i need to use it in a img tag, but it is not working - when i click the button it does not load the image onto it

any help would be appreciated

HTML

```
<img class="statusYes" src="Buttons/Button-Yes.png" ></img>
```

jQuery

```
$(".statusYes").click(function () {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(Buttons/Button-No.png)');
});
```

Comment: Why does your question and title say "button" when all you have is an image?

Comment: When you say "it does not load the image" do you mean it doesn't actually update the `background-image` property, or that you can't see the `background-image` because there's an image, the *actual `img`*, in the way of the `background-image`?

Comment: `</img>` really? And `<input>` = `<img>` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(".statusYes").click(function() {  
   $(this).prop("src","Buttons/Button-No.png"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that in your markup you put `<img src="...">` and then in the jQuery you try to put a new background to the img element via CSS which is done correctly by the browser, but not shown because it is drawn under the image you put in the src attribute.

you should try:

```
$(".statusYes").click(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'Buttons/Button-No.png');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".statusYes").click(function(){  
  $(this).css('background', 'url("Buttons/Button-No.png")'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest (given that you appear to be trying to toggle the `yes`/`no` options:

```
$(".status").click(function() {  
    $(this).prop("src",function (i,s){
        return "Buttons/Button-" + (s.indexOf('-No') > -1 ? 'Yes' : 'No') + '.png';
    });
});
```

This approach, obviously, adjusts the selector, leaving the 'status' to be determined by the current URL of the `src` property.